# ESAPI Upgrade from 2.0.1 to 2.2.2.0 getting the below exception

Tags: java, logging, owasp, esapi

While upgrading from 2.0.1 to 2.2.2.0 i am getting the below error

```
    Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception.
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:475)
    
    
    Caused by: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception.
        at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:129)
        at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.encoder(ESAPI.java:101)
    
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.owasp.esapi.logging.log4j.Log4JLogFactory
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.loadClassByStringName(ObjFactory.java:158)
```

I changed the `ESAPI.properties` also with the new changes for Log4JLogFactory.

Please suggest as I am not able to proceed on this.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68305702/557153

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESAPI - Getting ClassNotFoundException with ESAPI 2.2.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68305702/esapi-getting-classnotfoundexception-with-esapi-2-2-3-1)