# I have changed owasp.esapi 2.2.0.0 to 2.5.0.0 And I'm getting this org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory

Tags: java, owasp

```
Caused by: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory  LogFactory class (org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory ) must be in class path.
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:108)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.logFactory(ESAPI.java:139)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.getLogger(ESAPI.java:155)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.<init>
(DefaultEncoder.java:83)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.<init>(DefaultEncoder.java:106)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.getInstance(DefaultEncoder.java:67)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
```

I have ESAPI.properties in resourse with these values.

```
ESAPI.printProperties=true
LogLevel=INFO
ESAPI.Encoder=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder
Encoder.AllowMultipleEncoding=false
Encoder.AllowMixedEncoding=false
Encoder.DefaultCodecList=HTMLEntityCodec,PercentCodec,JavaScriptCodec

Logger.ApplicationName=My Test Application
Logger.LogEncodingRequired=false
Logger.LogApplicationName=true
Logger.LogServerIP=true
Logger.LogFileName=ESAPI_logging_file
Logger.MaxLogFileSize=10000000
Logger.UserInfo=true
Logger.ClientInfo=true
ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory
```

And created the  esapi-java-logging.properties as mentioned as [in this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68305702/esapi-getting-classnotfoundexception-with-esapi-2-2-3-1)

This is what I'm getting when I try to change the owasp.esapi version for vulnerabilities issues. And I have also changed the spring version to 5.2.30.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Java forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add a [mcve]?